# Converting the String of JSON Object to a Json object

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, object

I am new to the Javascript and react. Here I have following data which I have saved as a variable.

```
const data = {
    "data": {
      "getses": {
        "Id": "C174",
        "Name": "My first",
        "Images": [
          {
            "Name": "",
            "Value": {
              "Id": "C79"
            }
          },
          {
            "Name": "1",
            "Value": {
              "Id": "C79"
            }
          },
          {
            "Name": "2",
            "Value": {
              "Id": "C13"
            }
          }
        ],
        "ses": [
          {
            "Id": "C1757",
            "Name": "TEST1",
          }],
        }
       }
      }
```

Now, Here I want to use a map on the `ses`. but here , I am trying to get

```
data.data.ses
```

But it is not working. So, Can any one help me How Can I get this JSON object ?

Comment: You mean `data.data.getses.ses` ?

Comment: `data.data.getses.ses`

Comment: yes but not working

Comment: What you mean by "_not working_"? Please show us what you get when you use that in your code..

Comment: This is a very elementary question. It seems there wasn't any research done to solve it. Please research your problems beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

According your question. You should use this function

```
JSONT.parse(ur string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to look for `getses` before `ses`

```js
data.data.getses.ses
```

Answer (score 0):

Your referencing wrong property. Use this `data.data.getses.ses`

```js
const data = {
  data: {
    getses: {
      Id: "C174",
      Name: "My first",
      Images: [
        {
          Name: "",
          Value: {
            Id: "C79"
          }
        },
        {
          Name: "1",
          Value: {
            Id: "C79"
          }
        },
        {
          Name: "2",
          Value: {
            Id: "C13"
          }
        }
      ],
      ses: [
        {
          Id: "C1757",
          Name: "TEST1"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};
console.log(data.data.getses.ses);
```